# Added new scripts for vim functionality that is not working

Tags: vim

I am in a Mac OS and I just added some scripts to get new functionality from my vim editor and when I go back into the `vimrc` file I continue to get this error:

```
vim ~/.vimrc
Error detected while processing /Users/danale/.vimrc:
line   12:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
E15: Invalid expression: pathogen#infect()
```

I have looked at similar posts here that are not very helpful. Ultimately, I would like to use nerdtree configuration so I can use VIM as my IDE.

If I hit enter anyway, I get this error:

```
Error detected while processing VimEnter Auto commands for "*":
E492: Not an editor command:  NERDTree | endif
```

and it does not take me to a nerdtree type of view just an empty welcome to vim view.

Comment: Vim is a poorly designed editor with no plugin management system (it has a  convoluted plugin system, but no way to manage plugins). You need to install a plugin manager to work effectively with plugins. In this case, it looks like you're missing Vim Pathogen

Comment: The errors went away, so you can post your response as an answer. Still not getting the view I want, now I get the tree structure but no panel on the right like with an IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen).